# How to test elements are sorted in the list using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, ui-automation

Hi guys i am working on a apple UI Automation project where i have to test on a click of a button are elements in the list getting sorted properly or not ? can anyone help me to find how can i test it ?

Comment: In what form is the list? Do you have an array, or is it HTML elements?

Comment: It is a native IOS App , They are called UIElements

Comment: Are they sorted as numbers or strings?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to iterate over the elements in the list and verify that each element is smaller than the next one:

```
function is_sorted(arr) {
var len = arr.length - 1;
for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

}

You will have to adapt this code to sort UIElements, in particular the clause below:

```
arr[i] > arr[i+1]
```

Comment: This code doesn't apply to UIAutomation, in which the elements will actually be a [UIAElementArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementArrayClassReference/) of [UIAElement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/) objects.